# Can WebAssembly execution be disabled in browsers?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, web-assembly

I've recently found out about this new technology, which recently became a [World Wide Web Consortium recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly) and also that now almost all main browsers support it and it is enabled by default, see e.g. [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1342060).

I was not able to find in e.g. Firefox `about:config` to disable it:

[image: Firefox options for "wasm".]

Unlike JS:

[image: Firefox options for "javascript".]

As noted on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly), the technology poses maybe even higher risk than JS. How can one disable it in browsers if one so wishes?

Comment: "As noted on Wikipedia, the technology poses maybe even higher risk than JS." [unreliable source][not in citation given]

Comment: Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica wiki: "WebAssembly has been criticized for allowing greater ease of hiding the evidence for malware writers, scammers and phishing attackers." - that is what I based my phrase on. What have you meant?

Answer (score 2):

I did some more search and disabling is not complex. In e.g. https://github.com/stevespringett/disable-webassembly for Firefox one should:

> Enter about:config in the URL bar and change javascript.options.wasm
>   to false

I've checked with sample app https://subzey.github.io/wasm-canvas2d/ and it indeed changes working app to not-working.